# How to dynamically update my span with error message or success message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically update my span with a error message if the user types a character and deletes every thing typed and clicks a next field or show a success message as soon as the user stops typing.

my html:

```
 Full name:
<input type="text" id="box1" />&nbsp;<span id="msg_out1"></span>

 password:
<input type="password" id="box2" />&nbsp;<span id="msg_out2"></span>
```

My jQuery is this, at least this is what I have tried:

```
jQuery( "#box1" ).click(function(){
    if (jQuery( "#box1" ).val() !="") {
        jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10003; Great Name!').css('color','green').css('font-   size','18px').css('margin-left','40px');
    } else 
        jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10008; Please Enter Your Name').css('color','red').css('font-size','18px').css('margin-left','40px');
});
```

example: [twitter](https://twitter.com/signup)

Comment: Maybe you also want to empty the message while the user is typing. For that you would use keydown

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use the "change" event on the input.

So would do something like:

```
$('.my-input').on('change', function(event) {
    /* validate if blank or something*/
});
```

And that function will be called just when that input loses focus.

Comment: this does that exact same thing as .blur

Comment: @popnoodles that is just a mistake made typing it here, my original source has it

Comment: @user3052886 It does not do the exact same thing as blur. The onChange event is only called when the user has changed the value of the field. The onBlur event is fired when when the user has moved away from an object without necessarily having changed its value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The correct function is:

```
jQuery( "#box2" ).on('keyup',function(event){
    if (jQuery( "#box2" ).val() !="") {
    jQuery( "#msg_out2" ).html('&#10003; Great Name!').css('color','green').css('font-size','15px').css('margin-left','40px');
 }else 
    jQuery( "#msg_out2" ).html('&#10008; Please Enter Your Name').css('color','red').css('font-size','15px').css('margin-left','40px');

});
```